# Elfen lied OP- Lilium, Transcribed by TehIsher

Tags: piano, notation, articulation

[image: sheet]

There are dash lines below notes on the second and third measures do they do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an indication the note must be held for the full duration of the note, not any shorter. Kind of an anti-stattaco.